# Access Linked to sharepoint list is missing fields

Tags: access

I have linked to a SharePoint list from Access 2010 and after inserting additional fields into the list (via SharePoint) the fields do not appear even after deleting the linked table in Access and relinking. When importing from SharePoint all the fields are there for me to use.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and resolved it thus:

1. Go to File > Options > Current Database > Caching Web Service and SharePoint tables and select Clear Cache on Close.
2. Delete link to SharePoint table.
3. Close the DB and re-open.
4. Recreate the link to the SharePoint table.

HTH Max.

Comment: I had a situation where the column from the sharepoint list wouldn't show the data.  Other Access dbs showed the data, but even deleting and relinking the list wouldn't show the data in this one specific database.  The clearing cache instructions above solved this.  Kind of begs the question, "Why do they even HAVE that option (to cache)?!"