# Will deleting a table in an Access 2010 Database delete the List from SharePoint 2010 Server?

Tags: 2010, microsoft-access

I'm attempting to use this [fix](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/145501/77078) to recover missing fields that aren't appearing in Microsoft Access

I'm not sure if what I'm doing is deleting the link or deleting the list entirely. I'm right clicking on the name of the table in Access and selecting the "Delete" option. 
[image: Delete]
[image: Delete1]

Will deleting this table delete the list entirely?

Answer (score 0):

No it won't.  The link to the table will go away and anything youve built based on that linked table won't work... But the SharePoint List will still be on your site.  And if you find the need for it again, you can always relink it back in.